# Is there a less hard-coded alternative to using if (response.status === 201)?

Tags: javascript, fetch, response, http-status-codes

I am using the Fetch API to retrieve some external data for my application. Here is my code:

```
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/dictionary/define", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(values),
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 201) router.push("/");
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error));
```

I was wondering whether there was a cleaner/less hard-coded alternative to my `if (response.status === 201)` condition to indicate that everything went well?

Comment: There is `response.ok` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok but that won't work if you need to allow `201` exclusively. In that case I would assume your code will be as clean as it gets.

Comment: Do you mean that if I need to distinguish between, say, 200 and 201 using response.ok would not allow me to distinguish between the two?

Comment: Exactly, `response.ok` will just tell you the status code was in the range of 200-299.

Comment: What is "cleaner"? Any answers you receive will be opinions on the meaning of the word "clean" and what that means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider this code perfectly fine. You're looking for a 201 response so you do just that.

If you're only looking for a successful response just use `response.ok`.

The only cleanup I would consider to your existing code is storing all of your response status codes in a constant so it can be more human readable.

Something like this:

```
export const HttpStatusCodes = Object.freeze({
  Created: 201,
});
```

Then you could do `response.status === HttpStatusCodes.Created)` instead, which to me is much easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is cleaner and concise, you are doing your logic in single line and checking against your 201 status and redirecting it  so that is pretty much all good *thumbs up*. You are good to go mate :)

Answer (score 1):

The ok read-only property of the Response interface contains a Boolean stating whether the response was successful (status in the range 200-299) or not.

```
e.g. var myOK = response.ok;

// refactor with response.ok
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/dictionary/define", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(values),
  })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) router.push("/");
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok
Reference link here.

If you still don't need to specific status code itself, and only success, this will be great to fit your usecase. whatever status code is, you can detect request was success or not

Answer (score 1):

In case you are fine with knowing that the response succeeded with any status code in the range of 200 to 299, you can use `response.ok`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok

In case you explicitly require a 201 status code, there is no such shortcut and you need to check the `status` as demonstrated.